# Jhipster: ZonedDateTime in domain class is not getting converted to timestamp , instead getting converted to TINYBLOB in liquibase changelog file

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

I am using JHipster 4.1 and need help in adding new model.
I am trying to create my model class extending AbstractAuditingEntity class, but when I do mvnw liquibase:diff for changelog file generation the new file has TINYBLOB data type for timestamp. I am not sure why it is generating so.

```
> <column name="created_by" type="VARCHAR(50)">
>             <constraints nullable="false"/>
>          </column>
>          <column name="created_date" type="TINYBLOB">
>             <constraints nullable="false"/>
>          </column>
>          <column name="last_modified_by" type="VARCHAR(50)"/>
>          <column name="last_modified_date" type="TINYBLOB"/>
```

---

Can anyone please suggest why it is generating wrong datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Must be a limitation on Liquibase. Just take a look this issue:  https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6291

You can fix it manually in this way:

```
<column name="last_modified_date" type="timestamp"/>
```

More details here http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html